# ways of implementing constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I'm new to java, got control over basics, but following code makes me confuse about concept of constructor i.e. it seems different than what i studied (I'm not sure though, I'm beginner here)..so could somebody please explain it to me.

code I've got:

```
    public void Msg(String from, String to, String subject) {
        setFrom(from);
        setTo(to);
        setSubject(subject);
    }
```

I thought it would work same if i change it to following code :

```
    public void Msg(String from, String to, String subject) {
        setFrom = from;
        setTo = to;
        setSubject = subject;
    }
```

but it doesn't work after changing. Any one can please tell me what might be the reason behind this?

Comment: That's a method, not a constructor. Constructors don't have return types (`void`) and have the same name as the class. As for `setFrom(from)` to `setFrom = from` not working, `setFrom(from)` is a method call, needing a method declaration to exist to be able to do that. `setFrom = from` is assigning a variable. A variable `setFrom` needs to be declared to be able to do this. The syntax is not interchangable

Comment: Firstly, your constructor declaration is incorrect, since it cannot have a return type(`void`) in your case.

Comment: `setFrom` etc. is a method, so you cannot assign it a value.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood and mixed concept of constructor. but i got it at some extent. @VinceEmigh i was missing that thought. but you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetFrom is a method not a variable. If you want your constructor to be used like that you'll need something like the following.

```
private String from;
private String to;
private String subject;

public Msg(String from, String to, String subject) {
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    this.subject = subject;
}

public String getFrom() {
    return this.from;
}

public void setFrom(String from) {
    this.from = from;
}
```

Comment: I got it man. I got confused. but now i remember it was about difference between method and constructor

Answer (score 1):

Adding up to @Lachlan Goodhew-Cook, which is perfectly precise, you can also call methods within constructors, for the case when you add some data validation in your setters, for example:

```
    private String from;
    private String to;
    private String subject;

    public Msg(String from, String to, String subject) {

        // This is a call to your method defined below, passing the constructor
        // parameter (from) as an argument to setFrom()
        setFrom(from);

        // These access your data fields (instance variables) straight ahead
        // Need "this" keyword because constructor parameters have same name of data
        // fields (attributes) identifiers. "this" refers to your instance variables
        // being assigned the values passed as arguments to your constructor
        this.to = to;
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getFrom() {

        // Don't need "this" keyword
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String newFrom) {
        if (/*newFrom is valid input*/) {

            // Don't need "this" keyword
            from = newFrom;
        }
    }
```

This is just an example, to show you can call methods within constructors, as a possibility.

By the way, you only need to use the keyword `this` when your method/constructor parameters have the same name (identifiers) of your instance variables.